# How to remove Input format from comment form?

Tags: 6, input-formats

I used following code to create a module to remove input format from comment forms, but it doesn't work. Is there anything I'm missing or another way to do this ?

```
<?php
function comment_custom_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'comment_form') {
    foreach ($form['comment_filter']['format'] as $i => $filter) {
      if (is_int($i) && !$filter['#type']) {
        $form['comment_filter']['format'][$i]['#value'] = '';
        $form['comment_filter']['format'] = '';
        unset($form['preview']);
        unset($form['_author']);
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Administer > Site Configuration > Input Formats
```

Click configure for each of the formats, and edit which roles can see which format.

You can also look at [Better Formats](http://drupal.org/project/better_formats).

> Set the default format per role. Set the default format per content
>   type. Control allowed formats per content type. Hide format tips. Hide
>   more format tips link. Hide format selection for nodes, comments, and
>   blocks seperately, forcing the default to be used. Expand the
>   selection fieldset by default. Disable the expand/collapse of the
>   selection fieldset. Set selection fieldset title. Set more format tips
>   link text. Set default formats for nodes and comments separately.
>   Sensible defaults and fail overs for ease of use. Works with CCK
>   textareas. Works with Panels comment form. i18n module support for
>   user defined strings

.

Also if you want to hide it completely you can also unset the filter form element in your form alter but I don't think it is the right way to do it.

```
unset($form['comment_filter']['format']);
```

**NOTE: If you do so you will loose out on text processing and checks which drupal makes to make sure the html is safe.**

This should also work

```
$form['comment_filter']['format']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

This will make sure the format is not accessing to anyone.

---

Try this

```
function modulename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 if ($form_id == 'comment_form') {
  $form['comment_filter']['format']['#access'] = FALSE;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I want to completely remove input format. If I do as you say admin still can see the input format. any ideas ?

Comment: well, admin will always see everything and this is how it should be. You can create a different role called "Administrator" and give appropriate permissions

Comment: @Jake you can always use #access property to hide it from admin as well :). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Marius and junedkazi, @junedkazi what is #access property? can you explain a little bit? I think it's what i'm looking for.

Comment: @Jake check the last part of the answer I have given an example

Comment: Thanks junedkazi, I'm a little confused. I added this to my template.php or node.tpl.php but it didn't work. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: @Jake you need to do this in the form alter in your module file.

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong in my module and it doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Jake try the code I have updated in my answer. replace modulename with the name of the module.

Comment: Thanks again, This is the result:  `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare comment_form_alter() (previously declared in [path]\modules\comment\comment.module:488) in [path]\sites\all\modules\test\test.module on line 6`

Comment: @Jake the function name will be test_form_alter not comment_form_alter. It is alway the name of the module in which you place the code.